# Intersect an object with a curve

Tags: java, shapes, intersection, curve, path-2d

I created a curve with Path2D, and now i want to detect when an object intersect with the curve, not the rectangle that contains the curve. When i draw the curve, the line is contained within a rectangle, but I want to access the precise coordinates of the curve. I have literally no idea how to proceed.

Comment: We literally have no idea how to answer your question.  What curve?  What object?

Comment: Let's say i have a curve (PaintComponent) that I drew with public final void curveTo(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, double x3, double y3). Then I have another object, let's say a ball that i can move with the arrow keys. I wanna know if the ball has touch the curve.

Comment: I'm assuming you have the center and the radius of the circle.  Check if any point on the curve is within the radius of the center point.

Comment: The curve is not a closed object. I did not draw a circle, only a curved line.

Comment: Your ball is not a circle?  You have to keep a List of the points on the curve, and the radius and center point of the circle to do collision detection.  By the way, you can Google [collision detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_detection) to see how to detect the collision of various shapes.

Comment: Yea for the ball, i can simply do ball.getBounds(), but the curve is the problem

Comment: How can I find a list of all the points on the curve?

Comment: You create the List of Points, then draw the curve from the List as a series of drawLines.

Comment: Thanks i'll try creating my curves by using multiple lines.